# Need help retrieving data from a array dropbox

Tags: php, arrays, loops, post, echo

I have create a drop box with array which I have copied and used for a number of

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `select` is called `Rating`, not `rating` - you need to be case-sensitive!